# php declaration in loop? $image

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

im resizing an image using a $image. how can I make this:

```
    scaleImageFile(
        "gif/SB-99JCX-000021.gif",
        500,
        500,
        "gifanim/output/SB-99JCX-000021-500x500.gif",
        4
    );
```

into this? and make it work..

$image = is in a loop.. counting each image. so SB-99JCX-000021.gif, 22.gif, 23.gif... and so on

```
        scaleImageFile(
            "gif/$image",
            500,
            500,
            "gifanim/output/$image-500x500.gif",
            4
        );
```

more of the code to give you an idea:

```
foreach ($sortedImages as $image) {


        scaleImageFile(
            "gif/SB-99JCX-000021.gif",
            500,
            500,
            "gifanim/output/SB-99JCX-000021-500x500.gif",
            4
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just substitute the variable into the filenames:

```
foreach ($sortedImages as $image) {

    # Get the name of the image, stripped from image folder path and file type extension
    $name = substr($image,strlen($imagefolder),strpos($image, '.')-strlen($imagefolder));

    scaleImageFile(
        "gif/$name.gif",
        500,
        500,
        "gifanim/output/$name-500x500.gif",
        4
    );
}
```

You might also find the [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function to be useful, in place of your `substr` code. It can remove the directory prefix and a known extension. So you could write:

```
$name = basename($image, '.gif');
```

Comment: i simply need to add $image inside the scaleImageFile function (which is already in a loop).. can I do that? im a little new to this.

Comment: If that's what you want, then what's wrong with the original code in your question?

Comment: That's a problem with your IDE. PHP will expand variables inside double quotes. I use PhpStorm, and it colors the variables.

Comment: im using dreamweaver. the variable is not active inside the function "scaleImageFile". how do I make "$name" active?

Comment: I don't care what Dreamweaver says, the variable IS active in PHP.

Comment: it's treating it as text, instead of a variable.

Comment: Are you sure you have double quotes, not single quotes, around the string? Variables are expanded inside double quotes, not inside single quotes.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how DreamWeaver works. I thought it was just acting as a PHP IDE, but it sounds like it's doing its own rewriting of the code. I don't use it, your question wasn't about it. My answer is based on normal PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($sortedImages as $image) {

$name2 = basename($image, '.gif');
$location_vars = 'gif/'.$name2.'.gif';
$location_vars2 = 'gifanim/output/'.$name2.'-400x400.gif';

        scaleImageFile(
            $location_vars, //"gif/$name2.gif",
            400,
            400,
            $location_vars2, //"gifanim/output/$name2-500x500.gif",
            4
        );

}
```